# Using echo in bash puts last variable in front of the output

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a script and one of the parts of the script requires me to concatenate some variables together to create a URL.

```
REPO_URL='https://github.com/Example/Repo.Game/'
FILENAME='Example.Game-linux.zip'
latest_version="$(curl -LIs "${REPO_URL}/releases/latest" | grep -i '^location:' | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d'/' -f8)"

echo "$latest_version"
echo "$FILENAME"
echo "$REPO_URL"
echo "${REPO_URL}releases/download/${latest_version}/${FILENAME}"
```

Output:

```
2.0.5164
Example.Game-linux.zip
https://github.com/Example/Repo.Game/
/Example.Game-linux.ziple/Repo.Game/releases/download/2.0.5164
```

My actual output:

```
2.0.5164
Oxide.Rust-linux.zip
https://github.com/OxideMod/Oxide.Rust/
/Oxide.Rust-linux.zipideMod/Oxide.Rust/releases/download/2.0.5164
```

It looks like some kind of overflow problem? I'm not exactly sure. I added abcabc to the filename and the output became

```
/Oxide.Rust-linux.zipabcabc/Oxide.Rust/releases/download/2.0.5164
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello DrSulfurious, warning with GitHub.com output. All outputs are with CRLF (\r\n) at end of line like under Windows. Not single LF (\n). You can see them with a "`| cat -A`" after you script command line execution. "\r" are printed like "`^M`". So put a "`| dos2unix`" between "`curl`" and "`grep`"

Comment: @ArnaudValmary that's very insightful. Thank you for that advice.

Comment: GitHub has an API go collect this information reliably: https://docs.github.com/en/rest

Answer (score 1):

There is a cleaner way to get the version number, minus any trailing carriage-return, from github using `sed`.

```
latest_version =$(curl -LIs "${REPO_URL}/releases/latest" | sed -n 's/^Location:.*\/\([^\r]*\).*$/\1/p')
```

`sed` reads every line of input (STDIN by default) and performs operations on it defined by the action string parameter. The action string is a little tricky to explain in this case, but here goes:

1. The `-n` option suppresses the printing of each input line. Output will then only happen if it is explicitly stated in the action string.
2. The `s/[pattern]/[substitution]/p` construct says whenever you find `[pattern]`, replace it with `[substitution]` and print it. Our `[pattern]` is `^Location:.*\/\(.*\)$`, and our `[substitution]` is `\1`.
3. The expression `^` matches the beginning of the line.
4. The expression `.` means any single character, and the expression `.*` means any number of characters (including zero). This will match the largest possible string, so, for example `.*/` will match `abc/def/` in the string `abc/def/ghi`.
5. The expression `\/` just escapes the forward slash (because we are using backslash as a delimiter, we have to escape it).
6. The expression `\([pattern]\)` says any time you find `[pattern]`, remember it. in our case, it will remember whatever matches `[^\r]`.
7. The expression `[{chars}]` matches any one of the characters in `{chars}`. `[^{chars}]` matches any character that is not in {chars}. so `[^\r]*` matches any number of characters that is not a carriage return.
8. The expression `$` matches the end of a line.
9. The expression `\1` is replaced by the first remembered pattern.

So altogether, our action string says:

If you find a line that starts with `Location:`, followed by any number of characters, followed by a `/`, followed by any number of characters that are not a carriage return (which will be remembered), followed by any number of characters, followed by an end of line, then print the remembered characters.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by removing the carriage return value from the variable.

`tr -d '\r'` seems to have resolved it. I'm not sure where the variable came from and if anyone has advice on how to clean up this mess I would love some advice.

```
latest_version="$(curl -LIs "${REPO_URL}/releases/latest" | grep -i '^location:' | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d'/' -f8 | tr -d '\r')
```

Comment: Internet protocols (including http) generally follow the DOS/Windows convention that uses CR+LF line endings. See ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANSI quoting, and variable substitution to remove control characters from variables without having to invoke sub-shells.

ANSI quoting uses the special format `$'\*'` to represent special characters. For example use `$'\t'` for tab, `$'\n'` for new-line and `$'\r'` for carriage-return.

Variable substitution uses extra characters at the end of the variable name to perform actions on the variable. For example

1. `${variable//[pattern]/[substitution]}` will replace all instances of `[pattern]` in `${variable}` with `[substitution]`.
2. `${variable%[pattern]}` will remove `[pattern]` from `${variable}` if it is at the end.

By combining these two, you can remove carriage-return characters from the end of your variable like this:

```
echo ${variable%$'\r'}
```

Note: Variable substitution doesn't actually change the contents of the variable. To do that, you have to re-assign the result back to the variable:

```
variable="${variable%$'\r'}"
```